# How to remove dtype and Name from resulting pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Got the below result c(a pandas dataframe)for some operations. My question is how to remove Name and dtype from this result and extract plain values i.e `[3,1,1,3....]`. Is there any method to do that?

res contains indices, using  which I need to find corresponding rows in dfxn.

```
dfxn 
Out[207]: 
         0      1       2      3      4      5      6  7
0    14.38  14.21  0.8951  5.386  3.312  2.462  4.956  1
1    10.83  12.96  0.8099  5.278  2.641  5.182  5.185  3
2    16.77  15.62  0.8638  5.927  3.438  4.920  5.795  2
3    10.74  12.73  0.8329  5.145  2.642  4.702  4.963  3
4    20.16  17.03  0.8735  6.513  3.773  1.910  6.185  2


res
Out[206]: 
      0
0    90
1    78
2   115
3    38
4    43
5   103
6    14
7    23
8    39
9    21
10   67
11   53
12   59
13  110
14   93
15   96
16   89
17  114
18  124
19  131
.
.
.


while i<len(res):
      c[i]=dfxn.ix[res[i]]['7']
      i+=1


c
Out[196]:
  0
0 21 3
Name: 7, dtype: int64
1 90 1
Name: 7, dtype: int64
2 78 1
Name: 7, dtype: int64
3 115 3
Name: 7, dtype: int64
4 38 1
Name: 7, dtype: int64
5 43 1
Name: 7, dtype: int64
6 103 1
Name: 7, dtype: int64
7 14 3
```

Comment: Knowing what `res` and `dfxn` look like would be helpful, and please fix your indentation and make it clear what is actual code and what is IPython console output.

Comment: Hello Ajean, thanks for you suggestions.. I edited my question and added res and dfxn. Can you check it now?

Comment: Also for future reference, stack snippets don't work with python (they are only for Javascript, CSS, and HTML).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `c` may not be a DataFrame; it might probably a list of Series objects, which is why it's printing like that.  You can confirm or refute by looking at `type(c)`.  A better way to pull out the values, anyway, would be to use the indices as an array - you don't need to use a loop.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10), 'b':[i+5 for i in range(10)]})
res = pd.DataFrame([2,5,6,8])

c = df['b'].ix[res.values.ravel()]
print(c)
```

yields

```
2     7
5    10
6    11
8    13
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

In your case it would be

```
c = dfxn['7'].ix[res.values.ravel()]
```

Comment: It worked!! But c is a DataFrame.. I checked it..
type(c)
Out[219]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. Thanks for your help..